# EsLint error : Classname is not a Tailwind CSS class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, eslint

I keep having an EsLint error "className is not a TailwindCSS class" after adding some custom classes likes colors in my tailwindd.config.js and I don't find how to solve this problem.Shouldn't EsLint consider custom classes as tailwind class after adding them to the config file?

eslintrc.js:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const fs = require("fs")

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "next",
    "prettier",
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    babelOptions: {
      presets: [require.resolve("next/babel")],
    },
  },
  rules: {
    "testing-library/prefer-screen-queries": "off",
    "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      {
        argsIgnorePattern: "^_",
        varsIgnorePattern: "^_",
      },
    ],
    "sort-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        ignoreCase: true,
        ignoreDeclarationSort: true,
      },
    ],
    "tailwindcss/classnames-order": "off",
    "import/order": [
      1,
      {
        groups: ["external", "builtin", "internal", "sibling", "parent", "index"],
        pathGroups: [
          ...getDirectoriesToSort().map((singleDir) => ({
            pattern: `${singleDir}/**`,
            group: "internal",
          })),
          {
            pattern: "env",
            group: "internal",
          },
          {
            pattern: "theme",
            group: "internal",
          },
          {
            pattern: "public/**",
            group: "internal",
            position: "after",
          },
        ],
        pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ["internal"],
        alphabetize: {
          order: "asc",
          caseInsensitive: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

function getDirectoriesToSort() {
  const ignoredSortingDirectories = [".git", ".next", ".vscode", "node_modules"]
  return getDirectories(process.cwd()).filter((f) => !ignoredSortingDirectories.includes(f))
}

function getDirectories(path) {
  return fs.readdirSync(path).filter(function (file) {
    return fs.statSync(path + "/" + file).isDirectory()
  })
}
```

tailwind.config.js:

```
   /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme")

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "class",
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          50: "#eff6ff",
          100: "#dbeafe",
          200: "#bfdbfe",
          300: "#93c5fd",
          400: "#60a5fa",
          500: "#3b82f6",
          600: "#2563eb",
          700: "#1d4ed8",
          800: "#1e40af",
          900: "#1e3a8a",
        },
        bodyBg: "#252525",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        body: [
          "Inter",
          "ui-sans-serif",
          "system-ui",
          "-apple-system",
          "system-ui",
          "Segoe UI",
          "Roboto",
          "Helvetica Neue",
          "Arial",
          "Noto Sans",
          "sans-serif",
          "Apple Color Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Symbol",
          "Noto Color Emoji",
        ],
        sans: [
          "Inter",
          "ui-sans-serif",
          "system-ui",
          "-apple-system",
          "system-ui",
          "Segoe UI",
          "Roboto",
          "Helvetica Neue",
          "Arial",
          "Noto Sans",
          "sans-serif",
          "Apple Color Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Emoji",
          "Segoe UI Symbol",
          "Noto Color Emoji",
        ],
      },
      borderWidth: {
        DEFAULT: "1px",
        0: "0",
        2: "2px",
        3: "3px",
        4: "4px",
        6: "6px",
        8: "8px",
      },
      minHeight: {
        ...defaultTheme.height,
      },
      minWidth: {
        ...defaultTheme.width,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Probably the `eslint-plugin-tailwindcss` does not pick up the custom tailwind config and it uses the default config as fallback.  Is `tailwind.config.js` in the same folder with the `eslintrc.js` file? Can you share the (simplified) folder structure of your project?

Comment: I found a solution which is, I guess, not the best practice, but worked. I removed that line from thhe eslintrc.js :     // "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended",

About the folder structure, both files are in the same folder. I can try to add the folder structure if necessary

Comment: So actually you dropped `eslint-plugin-tailwindcss`?

Comment: Maybe the following suggestion might work for you: https://github.com/francoismassart/eslint-plugin-tailwindcss/issues/241#issuecomment-1537851714.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you have properly defined your custom classes in your Tailwind CSS
configuration in tailwind.config.js file.Make sure the classes you're using in
your code match the custom classes you've defined in your configuration.To make
ESLint recognize custom Tailwind CSS classes, add your custom classes to the
"tailwindcss/classnames-order" rule in your ESLint configuration :
"tailwindcss/classnames-order": [ "error", { //code here... "custom-classes": [
"primary-50", "primary-100", //Add your code ], }, ],

Comment: Are you saying that every custom class has to be added to the eslintrc file?